# C++ effective approach to container for one-time lookup but multiple traverses and accesses

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, unordered-map

When building the array/vector from elements in my problem, I need to check if they are not already inserted, i.e., not allow duplicates. Instead of using array/vector I can use set/map/unordered_map. However, I want to maintain the insertion order which makes set/map unusable and after I fill this container with data, I only want access and ability to traverse the container as fast as possible. The unordered_map has amortized lookup and also traverse step at O(1) but it is not guaranteed. So my solution was to create both vector and unordered_map, add element into both, use the unordered_map for checking if the element should be inserted to both and further only use vector. Does this make any sense or is there a more convenient and effective way?

Comment: @Ron Sure but my question is more about how to tackle this situation to get the best possible result out of it, if there is a way how to do it better. The other option I considered was to use only the unordered_map so I don't spend extra memory and also not have to insert twice, but I think doing it the way I described is better.

Comment: How big of a vector are we talking about?  A linear search over a vector with a few hundred items in it is really quite fast.

Comment: I think it makes a lot of sense to try this approach, but the only real way to know which one is better is to measure.

Comment: @NathanOliver In most cases between hundreds and thousands of elements, in edge cases tens of thousands (estimate). However, I do the cycle with "one lookup and multiple accesses/traverses" multiple times for the clusters which are created.

Comment: @super Yep, retrospectively I can do that but currently I don't have the actual live instances at hand, so I wondered if the idea behind it is sound as it seemed a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this make any sense or is there a more convenient and effective way?

That generally made a lot of sense, and will scale optimally, though for the problem as described you'd only need an `unordered_set` to track already-inserted elements, rather than an `unordered_map` with some arbitrary/irrelevant values (e.g. `true`).

If further optimisations are needed...

- when the number of elements is small (e.g. hundreds, but do some benchmarks to work out the exact threshold that works for your data), consider just using a vector and brute-force search for duplicates; if you can generate high quality hash values cheaply from your keys, then that could be optimised with a [*bloom filter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), so you're rarely doing a brute-force search for previously-unseen elements (if repeated elements are relatively unusual, then a bloom filter could even be a useful first step before consulting an `unordered_set`)
- If you know how many elements to expect - use
  [`unordered_set::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve)
  and
  [`vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)
  before inserting elements.
- You could use a faster hash table.  For smallish keys, and when only doing insertions as you've described, closed hashing / open addressing tends to be much faster than the separate chaining that `unordered_set` uses.  You can find a fairly recent comparison of OSS hash tables [here](https://martin.ankerl.com/2019/04/01/hashmap-benchmarks-01-overview/).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth analysis and especially for pointing out the unordered_set. Use of the map felt awkward to me but somehow I did not think to look for better suited data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to make containers (apart form arrays) with a lookup of O(1). There will be tradeoffs what so ever. Hash maps/ tables are no exception. But if you tune in the bucket size of `std::unordered_map`, it can be quite fast when working with a lot of data. But still your talking about nanoseconds.

One method which the CryEngine uses which in most cases are faster than the traditional `std::unordered_map` is, they use a `std::vector` to store the entries. This means that it performs better than links which the unordered map uses. This improves locality and thus less cache misses. The way they do it is, the vector works like a set. After inserting an entry, it sorts it and when looking up, it binary searches its way. This did work a lot fast.

Another alternative is the Google [Sparse Hash](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash) which is said to be one of the most efficient hash tables. Another is the EA's standard library [hash table](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/hash_map.h). These are just a few in many.

In your case, until we profile it, we cant know for sure. But a small note, if your going to insert elements to both the `std::unordered_map` and `std::vector` your talking about two separate `new` calls (it depends though). It might not benefit you well (when inserting).

Comment: Thanks for the info and tips to the alternatives. I'm not sure if I understand correctly the description with CryEngine, but I can't sort, because the ordering holds information in my problem.

Comment: @eXPRESS what I said with CryEngine is that they use a sorted vector which has better insert and lookups than the unordered map. If you can sort then it isn't an option.